# Javascript 'this' not returning object clicked on

Tags: javascript

i have an anchor tag generated in my code behind that calls a function with

```
href="javascript:blah('string',this);"
```

I need to interact with the object but it doesn't seem to be returning the correctly.  When I alert this it returns "object Window" and calls to this.id return undefined (the anchor has an ID)

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the href for your click event use an inline onClick handler. This will give you the proper "this" object.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="blah('string',this);">
```

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? Is the example `href` what you're trying to generate or what appears in the source code?

Assuming the link is generated correctly, this is entirely a JavaScript question.

Different browsers have slightly different implementations of event handlers. Consider using JQuery to gloss over these inconsistencies and give yourself a much easier job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. currently I am in firefox but it will need to work in IE7 as well.  The example is what appears in the html source. Also I am working with jquery and tried to use $(this) initially but that didnt work iether

Comment: With JQuery, I'd work the other way - when the form loads, do something like: `$.('Link Selector').Click(function() { alert(this;) })`

Answer (score 0):

```
href="javascript:blah('string',this);"
```

inside function blah `this` refer to `window` object

do this

```
<a href="javascript:" id="myLink">


function handle()
{
// this refers to your link
}
document.getElementById('myLink').onclick=handle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get everything working even if javascript is disabled.

```
<a href="#objectToInteractWithOrAnUriWithoutTheHash" onclick="return blah(this);">test</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
   function blah(link) {
      var elementIdOrUri = link.href;

      //do some crazy stuff.

      //false will prevent the browser from visiting the link
      return false;
     }
</script>
```

Since you are using a href in this case, the element (if it got an anchor) or the uri will be visited if javascript is disable. Your function will be invoked otherwise.